# Java Android : onTouchListener release?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

Java/android noob here, I have a problem where using onTouchListener I change the variable x to x+1 and that works fine, but when I release I would like the x variable to decrease in value until it hits zero, like so:

```
    Imageview image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fgView);

    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
            {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    mode=1;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                mode=2;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                mode2=2;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                mode=1;

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                mode2=1;

                break;
            }

        }
       if(mode==1){
       x++;
       }

       if(mode==2){
       x * 0.9
       }

       //mode2 is filler

     }
```

Now that works fine, my problem comes when I want my x to continue to decrease after release, but since it's under setOnTouchListener then it doesn't work. 
Maybe something like this:

```
     public boolean onTouchFalse(View v){
          if(x>0){
              x * 0.9
          }
     }
```

or even something like

```
     public boolean image.isOnScreen{
         if(x>0){
            x = x * 0.9
         }
     }
```

tl;dr: I'm looking for some kind of listener that I could use to depreciate my x.

Is there a listener or some class i'm missing? Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Just a tip,  you can't do x * 0.9, but you can do x *= 0.9.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking into timers.  Check my edit though, and I know x*0.9 is not real code.

Comment: That top section of code looks like it might work,  I know there has to be some android listener where you can get the state of the button (pressed/not pressed) but I don't have a javadoc in front of me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();


    image.post( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            x--;
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);

        }
    });
```

** Note that the 100 is how long in between each subtraction (in millisecs)

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly how I wanted.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are no touch events if you're not touching the screen. Events need a trigger, maybe a timer could help.

Comment: Thanks that could work, the word I was looking for is recurring. :P